# What is the national median salary in Poland?

Tags: data-request, census, poland

The mean average salary in Poland is blown out of proportion by extremely high salaries of people in management and government jobs. Meanwhile, finding a 'common' job that pays anywhere close to the country's average is very difficult.

I believe using median average would show the more realistic salary level, and what common people can actually afford - but my search for any sources that would give median salary as opposite to mean average have proven unsuccessful so far.

Both gross income and net pay are okay - converting between one and the other for incomes in the lower range is rather straightforward. A source of this data, that either records it over time or gives current value, updated over time would be preferred, but in absence of such, a momentary, current/recent data point would suffice.

Comment: Are saying that government jobs *in general* are extremely high?

Comment: @gerrit: In the times of "People's Republic of Poland" the gap was quite minimal. Sure the govt. got access to better wares and facilities but actual income was on par with highly qualified engineering jobs. Nowadays - tenfold the average is not uncommon, and so the average is skewed.

Comment: Even for "ordinary" civil servants, policemen, teachers, national park officers, clerks at the local city hall...?

Comment: @gerrit: Government jobs, not 'budget sector' jobs. Politicians and people working directly for the politicians (advisors, top-level administration, organizations acting on behalf of government bodies etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Eurostat's [earnings database](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/labour-market/earnings/database). There you will find the mean, median, 10th percentile and 90th percentile for [hourly](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/earn_ses_hourly), [monthly](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/earn_ses_monthly) and [annual](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/earn_ses_annual) earnings. These are gross earnings. For the moment there is data for 2002, 2006 and 2010. According to Eurostat, [an update is due in 2016, with figures for 2014](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/labour-market/earnings).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Gross National Income (GNI) per capita from the Work Bank statistics:

http://data.worldbank.org/country/poland

The Organization of Economic Cooperation and Development (OECD) has summary employment and economic statistics per country:

http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=35253

UPDATE: The Central Statistics Office of Poland publishes macro-economic information on a monthly and annual basis (e.g., average salary, unemployment, etc):

http://stat.gov.pl/en/poland-macroeconomic-indicators/

Comment: Dividing GNI by employed population will give me the mean average, not median. I believe [this chart](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIN2AVE) might enable me to calculate the median based on mean average for 2012, if I only understood what it actually represents...

Comment: Select the "i" icon next to the "minimum relative to average wages ..." selection. A popup will appear explaining it.

Comment: "Minimum relative to average wages of full-time workers", mean 0.38, median 0.47. 0.38/0.47=0.808; that would be the mean to median rate for average salary. 2012 mean average net pay was [2520PLN](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Arednia_krajowa) which would set median at 2037PLN. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: GNI is still quite far from wages and salaries. It's not a good proxy.